# Reuse responsive spacing in TailwindCSS

Tags: tailwind-css

Can I reuse responsive spacing classes in TailwindCSS?

I'd like to create dynamic classes like `p-sm` to apply:

`p-1 sm:p-2 lg:p-3`

or `mb-responsive-lg` to apply:

`mb-2 sm:mb-3 lg:mb-4`

Obviously I can't create all classes related to it, I want to define suffix like "sm" or "responsive-sm" and apply it to all spacing related classes, can I achieve that with plugins?

Answer (score 0):

you could use [class-variance-authority](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-variance-authority). example from its page

```
import { cva } from "class-variance-authority";

const button = cva(["font-semibold", "border", "rounded"], {
  variants: {
    intent: {
      primary: [
        "bg-blue-500",
        "text-white",
        "border-transparent",
        "hover:bg-blue-600",
      ],
      // **or**
      // primary: "bg-blue-500 text-white border-transparent hover:bg-blue-600",
      secondary: [
        "bg-white",
        "text-gray-800",
        "border-gray-400",
        "hover:bg-gray-100",
      ],
    },
    size: {
      small: ["text-sm", "py-1", "px-2"],
      medium: ["text-base", "py-2", "px-4"],
    },
  },
  compoundVariants: [
    {
      intent: "primary",
      size: "medium",
      class: "uppercase",
      // **or** if you're a React.js user, `className` may feel more consistent:
      // className: "uppercase"
    },
  ],
  defaultVariants: {
    intent: "primary",
    size: "medium",
  },
});

button();
// => "font-semibold border rounded bg-blue-500 text-white border-transparent hover:bg-blue-600 text-base py-2 px-4 uppercase"

button({ intent: "secondary", size: "small" });
```

The above example is shown for the button. so you pass the variants to the component as a prop.

```
<button {...props} className={button({  intent: props.intent, size: props.size })}>
  Button
</button>
```

You can apply above logic to spacing component

Comment: oh a great tool to help manage classes, but I think it's not the answer for dynamic variants